# Where did the T-Rex come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, jurassic-park

Although there is no disputing the impact that Steven Spielberg's [*Jurassic Park*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107290/) had when it was released in 1992, there has always been one scene that has bugged/perplexed me.

I speak of the climax, when Alan Grant et al are surrounded by the Velociraptors and about to be pounced upon, when suddenly the T-Rex lunges in and 'saves the day'.

It has already been established earlier on the film that the T-Rex telegraphs its approach with thunderous footsteps, and I'm pretty sure that even if the humans were surrounded by malevolent reptiles, they would notice a huge T-rex squeezing in through the front door of the reception center.

Possible explanations include the T-Rex's ambushing skills (as evident in the earlier Gallimimus chasing scene), the afore-mentioned distraction of the Velociraptors, or even a huge suspension of disbelief to better serve the dynamism of the scene.

I don't like the idea of T-Rex just being shoehorned into the scene to add some va va voom, so is there a better explanation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well I never wondered about this. There has been quite a chaos (with them falling through the ceiling into these skeletons) immediately before it, under which an approaching T-Rex could really get lost.

So I would indeed attribute this to the distraction created by the velociraptors and the overall chaos of this scene (both for the audience and the characters). And maybe a bit of trying to create a very surprising moment by sacrificing a small bit of realism (which never bothered me at all).

Comment: T Rex couldve taken an alternate route into the building. :)

Comment: Or he just had crawled in for a nap... and the whole ruckus the raptors made woke him up? Sure would make ME grumpy ;).

Comment: The T-Rex was being vewwy, vewwy careful. It didn't want it's prey to escape.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest answer is that the T-Rex didn't come in through the main doors, it came through the (now open to the elements) side entrance, shouldering its way through the scaffolding:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Needs freehand circles.

Comment: @CapyStenchbeast - I'm sad that I forgot the gigantic red arrow on the bottom picture...

Answer (score 1):

In the movie, when the camera pans to the t-rex, if you look in the background there's a large door or opening in the background that it looks like the t-rex came through.